# PHP: Does it make a difference to replace an array() by a function which just returns it?

Tags: php, syntax, return-type

Please apologize, I didn't find a better title. I'm new to PHP and reviewing a commit where someone replaced some values by functions which are actually returning these. This does not make sense to me. But I assume it was done for a certain reason. Can somebody please help me here? Thanks!

```
protected function _getHeaderListForRequest()
{
     return array();
}

protected function _postProcessResponse($response)
{
    return $response;
}


// BEFORE
$http->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $this->getApiEndpoint(), '1.1', array(), $this->_buildQuery($request));
// REPLACED BY
$http->write(Zend_Http_Client::POST, $this->getApiEndpoint(), '1.1', $this->_getHeaderListForRequest(), $this->_buildQuery($request));

// JUST ADDED - BUT $repsonse = $response or not?
$response = $this->_postProcessResponse($response);
```

Comment: Ask the person who made the commit?

Comment: It comes down to the same.

Comment: It`s possible that this is a preparation for future implementation, but I'm only guessing here...

Comment: This is most likely done for further extensions. For now it just returns the values, but in the future if the response needs to be somehow processed (validated, etc), this can be done in the _postProcessResponse method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm glad I'm not so stupid. Preparation for future implementation make actually sense.